# System Data OleDb OleDbException: 'No value given for one or more required parameters.'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, asp.net-web-api

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBvoy.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSAci.png

Everytime I Submit the form, instead of sending me the info in Access it gives me this error.

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;



public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string fn = "", sn = "", un = "", ea = "", pa = "", by = "", co = "", msg2 = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlS = "";

        string fileName = "RegDatabase.mdb";



        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            fn = Request.Form["first_name"];
            sn = Request.Form["sur_name"];
            un = Request.Form["user_name"];
            ea = Request.Form["email_address"];
            pa = Request.Form["pass"];
            by = Request.Form["birth_year"];
            co = Request.Form["country"];


            int bYear = int.Parse(by);


            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [SignUpDatabase] WHERE User_name = '" + un + "'";
            if (!MyAdoHelper.IsExist(fileName, selectQuery))
            {
                sqlS = "INSERT INTO [SignUpDatabase] VALUES ('" + fn + "','" + sn + "','" + un + "'," + ea + "'," + pa + "'," + by + "'," + co + ")";

                MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName, sqlS);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code if you need it.
idk what more detail to give you.

Comment: [An image of your code is not helpful](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Copy and paste the code you have questions about, or better create an [mcve], into the question. Use the code formatting feature to make sure others can read it easily.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. For any specific problem you are having please include a [mcve]. Please also read [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) and [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask). Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic). Also, be sure to take the [tour] (you get a badge!).

Comment: Please learn and use parameterized sql statements, rather than string concatination.

Comment: So many problems here. Put aside for the moment the problem of Sql Injection when you concatenate strings together, but what do you think will happen if one of those strings contains a single quote? And an INSERT without specifying the fields requires you to pass values for every field in the table, now look at the quotes missing before ea, pa, by. Again nothing of this would happen if you start to use parameters

Comment: Inspect that `sqlS` for syntax errors. Fix them, then try entering a `'` in one of those textboxes. Then use parameters to fix that and more

Comment: Finally that _MyAdoHelper_ seems like one of those homemade _do_it_all_ class that just make, in the long run, your life more miserable.

Comment: You can get that "required parameters missing" error when you make a typo in a column name, or accidentally (by missing quotes) have some word where the query expects a column or parameter

Answer (score -2):

Use the correct syntax - and `by` should be numeric.:

```
sqlS = "INSERT INTO [SignUpDatabase] VALUES ('" + fn + "','" + sn + "','" + un + "','" + ea + "','" + pa + "'," + by + ",'" + co + "')";
```

Comment: Please use parameters to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: @user9938: Please stick to the question. A direct question deserves a direct answer. Further, values are fetched from a stored record, thus no injection, and even if so, Access SQL cannot run inline action queries. That said, I, as most others, prefer parameters due to the cleaner code.