# System Data OleDb OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ms-access, asp.net-web-api

This is the error:
[image]

Access database table:

[image]

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;



public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public string fn = "", sn = "", un = "", ea = "", pa = "", by = "", co = "", msg1 = "", msg2 = "";
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sqlS = "";

        string fileName = "RegDatabase.mdb";



        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            fn = Request.Form["first_name"];
            sn = Request.Form["sur_name"];
            un = Request.Form["user_name"];
            ea = Request.Form["email_address"];
            pa = Request.Form["pass"];
            by = Request.Form["birth_year"];
            co = Request.Form["country"];


            int bYear = int.Parse(by);


            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM [SignUpDatabase] WHERE Username = '" + un + "'";
            if (!MyAdoHelper.IsExist(fileName, selectQuery))
            {
                sqlS = "INSERT INTO [SignUpDatabase] VALUES ('" + fn + "','" + sn + "','" + un + "','" + ea + "','" + pa + "'," + by + ",'" + co + "')";

                MyAdoHelper.DoQuery(fileName, sqlS);


            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand why it doesnt work.[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5nwv.png)
[html of table of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWnHB.png)

So I just want the user to input login info ok? and then it sends everything to access database.
but it doesnt work and show this error. please help.

Comment: We have [already told you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70840765/system-data-oledb-oledbexception-no-value-given-for-one-or-more-required-param) to use parameters and do not concatenate strings to create the sql command. Now it seems that you have solved the previous error but still in the wrong way. Using parameters and giving the proper datatype to each parameter will resolve the problem

Comment: I think that you have also two more problems. The table seems to have 7 fields with one being an autonumber. You pass 7 values with a _password_ value that has no matching field in the shown table. This makes the engine trying to insert the _first_name_ as the autonumber hence the type mismatch. Use the proper syntax _INSERT INTO (<field_list>) values (<value_list>)_

Comment: @Steve I dont understand what datatype I am supposed to give them. if I will just add String to fn = Request.Form["first_name"]; it wont change anything

Comment: As others have already stated, use parameters. [OLEDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb?view=netframework-4.8) doesn't use named parameters, so the order in which the parameters is added is important. See [OleDbParameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter?view=netframework-4.8) for more information.

Comment: @Steve let me try what you said now.